# AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__' while fetching value from textfield

Tags: python, attributeerror, kivymd

Here is the exerpt of my code on the .py side that cause the problem:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window

KV = """
ScreenManager:
    LoginScreen:
<LoginScreen>:
    name: 'login'
    Screen:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'vertical'
            MDBottomNavigation:
                MDBottomNavigationItem:
                    name: 'screen 1'
                    text: 'Login'
                    icon: 'login'                 

                    MDTextField:
                        id: user_id
                        hint_text:"Enter user name"
                        icon_right:"account"
                        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5} 
                        size_hint_x:0.76

                    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                        text:'Login'
                        size_hint_x:0.4
                        font_size:17
                        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.3}
                        on_press: app.login_fun()

"""
class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass

class OneApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Green'
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return self.screen

    def login_fun(self):
        value = self.screen.ids.user_id.text
        print("What you typed is: ", value)

OneApp().run()
```

I am trying to get value of user input in the main class. but it shows me the error:

```
>  Traceback (most recent call last):                                   
> File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 861, in
> kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__                            
> KeyError: 'user_id'                                                   
> 
>                                                                                                                                                                 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:   
> 
>                                                                                                                                                                 Traceback (most recent call last):                                    
> File "D:\Working_dir\Programming\Python\Kivy-MD\test.py", line 164, in
> <module>                                                              
> 
>      MyApp().run()                                                                                                                                                File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py",
> line 950, in run                                             
>      runTouchApp()                                                                                                                                                File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py",
> line 582, in runTouchApp                                    
>      EventLoop.mainloop()                                                                                                                                         File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py",
> line 347, in mainloop                                       
>      self.idle()                                                                                                                                                  File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py",
> line 391, in idle                                           
>      self.dispatch_input()                                                                                                                                        File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py",
> line 342, in dispatch_input                                 
>      post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))                                                                                                                                 File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py",
> line 248, in post_dispatch_input                            
>      listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)                                                                                                                    File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in
> kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch                                  
> File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py",
> line 1412, in on_motion                     
>      self.dispatch('on_touch_down', me)                                                                                                                           File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in
> kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch                                  
> File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py",
> line 1428, in on_touch_down                 
>      if w.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):                                                                                                                       File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in
> kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch                                  
> File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py",
> line 1198, in on_touch_down                    
>      return super(ScreenManager, self).on_touch_down(touch)                                                                                                       File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py",
> line 545, in on_touch_down                            
>      if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):                                                                                                                   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in
> kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch                                  
> File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\relativelayout.py",
> line 297, in on_touch_down                    
>      ret = super(RelativeLayout, self).on_touch_down(touch)                                                                                                       File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py",
> line 545, in on_touch_down                            
>      if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):                                                                                                                   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in
> kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch                                  
> File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\relativelayout.py",
> line 297, in on_touch_down                    
>      ret = super(RelativeLayout, self).on_touch_down(touch)                                                                                                       File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py",
> line 545, in on_touch_down                            
>      if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):                                                                                                                   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in
> kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch                                  
> File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py",
> line 545, in on_touch_down                            
>      if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):                                                                                                                   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in
> kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch                                  
> File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py",
> line 1198, in on_touch_down                    
>      return super(ScreenManager, self).on_touch_down(touch)                                                                                                       File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py",
> line 545, in on_touch_down                            
>      if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):                                                                                                                   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in
> kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch                                  
> File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\relativelayout.py",
> line 297, in on_touch_down                    
>      ret = super(RelativeLayout, self).on_touch_down(touch)                                                                                                       File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py",
> line 545, in on_touch_down                            
>      if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):                                                                                                                   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in
> kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch                                  
> File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py",
> line 545, in on_touch_down                            
>      if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):                                                                                                                   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in
> kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch                                  
> File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py",
> line 545, in on_touch_down                            
>      if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):                                                                                                                   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in
> kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch                                  
> File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py",
> line 1198, in on_touch_down                    
>      return super(ScreenManager, self).on_touch_down(touch)                                                                                                       File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py",
> line 545, in on_touch_down                            
>      if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):                                                                                                                   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in
> kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch                                  
> File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\relativelayout.py",
> line 297, in on_touch_down                    
>      ret = super(RelativeLayout, self).on_touch_down(touch)                                                                                                       File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py",
> line 545, in on_touch_down                            
>      if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):                                                                                                                   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in
> kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch                                  
> File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py",
> line 545, in on_touch_down                            
>      if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):                                                                                                                   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in
> kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch                                  
> File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\behaviors\ripple_behavior.py",
> line 255, in on_touch_down       
>      super().on_touch_down(touch)                                                                                                                                 File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\button.py",
> line 969, in on_touch_down                          
>      return super().on_touch_down(touch)                                                                                                                          File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py",
> line 151, in on_touch_down                  
>      self.dispatch('on_press')                                                                                                                                    File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 705, in
> kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch                                  
> File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1248, in
> kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch                                   
> File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1132, in
> kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch                                  
> File
> "C:\Users\Shourov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py",
> line 57, in custom_callback                         
>      exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)                                                                                                                             File "<string>", line 70, in <module>                                 
> File "D:\Working_dir\Programming\Python\Kivy-MD\test.py", line 159, in
> login_fun                                                             
> 
>      print(self.screen.ids.user_id.text)                                                                                                                          File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 864, in
> kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__                            
> AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'         
> [Finished in 4.30s with exit code 1]
```

As you saw, I want to get the text of my textfield when press login button, but maybe there is a better way to do that. Can anyone explain the reason of this error and how to overcome this problem please?

Comment: Can you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? What parts of the layout seem to be relevant to causing the problem? Also, why not use a separate .kv file?

Comment: Sorry for the ugly code. Actually I am a beginner so so that I feel comfortable in this style. in LoginScreen  class > MDBottomNavigation > MDBottomNavigationItem (screen 1) > second BoxLayout > TextField (id : use_id). I am trying to fetch the text of Textfield in MyApp class.

Comment: I mean, can you reproduce the problem using a simpler layout?

Comment: I've reproduced the problem using a simpler layout. Would you please check now the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using following script.

Code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window

KV = """
ScreenManager:
    DemoScreen:
<DemoScreen>:
    name: 'demo'
    Screen:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'vertical'
            MDBottomNavigation:
                MDBottomNavigationItem:
                    name: 'screen 1'
                    text: 'Login'
                    icon: 'login'                 

                    MDTextField:
                        id: user_id
                        hint_text:"Enter user name"
                        icon_right:"account"
                        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5} 
                        size_hint_x:0.76

                    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                        text:'Login'
                        size_hint_x:0.4
                        font_size:17
                        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.3}
                        on_press: app.login_fun()

"""
class DemoScreen(Screen):
    pass

class OneApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Green'
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return self.screen

    def login_fun(self):
        value = self.screen.get_screen('demo').ids.user_id.text
        print("What you typed is: ", value)

OneApp().run()
```